# Jax-ws 2.2 or Metro as Tomcat runtime environment

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I need an implementation of JAX-WS, that is RUNTIME ENVIRONMENT to use a client

for Tomcat6.

Which is better in your opinion?

JAX-WS 2.2 
https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/2.2/

Metro 2.0 https://metro.dev.java.net/2.0/

They have different installation procedures and different jars.

For now I only need to be able to run a client from under Tomcat6 web apps.

But later I'm planning to use ApacheCXF soap web-service, that will run on this Tomcat.

As I understand, CXF is a unique implementation that does not any of mentioned runtime environments,
so I guess whatever between metro & jax-ws2.2 I choose does not matter, right?

Still, which one do you recommend?

Comment: Why not use CXF from the start?

Comment: @skaffman What do you mean? Does CXF also have its own runtime environment that will allow us to run web-service jax-ws clients under tomcat? If so, can you give a link that points on how to install this jax-ws environment under tomcat!!

Comment: I must add that our clients are NOT generated with CXF. But they must run under what we're supposed to install on Tomcat.

Answer (score 4):

The Metro 2.0 release consists of following components:

- WSIT 2.0 - Browse the WSIT release notes online.
- JAX-WS RI 2.2 - Browse the JAX-WS RI release notes online.
- JAXB RI 2.2 - Browse the JAXB RI release notes online.

In other words, the JAX-WS implementation you get in Metro 2.0 **is** JAX-WS RI 2.2. But if that's the only part you need, why installing Metro? Just use JAX-WS RI.

Comment: Metro has a simpler installation procedure! You don't need to write anything to config xml files ! But I see the point. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Are there any specific features of Jax-WS 2.2 that you require that aren't available in Jax-ws 2.0? The main advantage being that if you use 2.0, that's "included" right the the runtime of Java 1.6, no additions required. I'm using it very successfully for supplying Java SOAP services to Sharepoint Web parts that its almost disappointing...I remember struggling with web services "back in the day", now its, "add a couple of annotations to a pojo...done."